# Airflow: RBAC with flask, werkzeug.routing.BuildError

Tags: airflow, flask-appbuilder

I am trying to configure RBAC (setting a `webserver_config.py` of Flask-AppBuilder) with AUTH_LDAP, and after successfully logging through LDAP, I am getting the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/templates/appbuilder/navbar_menu.html", line 47, in top-level template code
    <li>{{ menu_item(item2) }}</li>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 574, in _invoke
    rv = self._func(*arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/templates/appbuilder/navbar_menu.html", line 21, in template
    <a tabindex="-1" href="{{item.get_url()}}">
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/menu.py", line 24, in get_url
    return url_for(f"{self.baseview.endpoint}.{self.baseview.default_view}")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 370, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2215, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 358, in url_for
    endpoint, values, method=method, force_external=external
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 2020, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'BaseView.list'. Did you mean 'DagModelView.list' instead?
```

I am using airflow 1.10.9 with werkzeug==0.16.0.
Do you have any hints, please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the problem and fixed the problem.

It was related to the RBAC activation (in airflow) and a previous plugin of mines, which hadn't `default_view = "index"` defined in Plugin's view.